# Why is there this strange contradiction between the language of logic and that of set theory?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, logic, notation

In standard probability theory events are represented by sets consisting of elementary events. Consider two events for which (as sets) $A \subset B$. If an elementary event $x \in A$ takes places then we say that $B$ takes place as well. Since $A \subset B$, $x \in A$ implies that $B$ takes place too.

It seems that when for sets (representing events) $$A \subset B$$ $$then \ A \ implies \ B .$$

On the other hand, if we use the language of logic for the events then $$A \supset B$$ $$ \ means\  that \ A\  implies\ B .$$

Why is this strange virtual contradiction between the language of sets and the language of logic?

(In order to avoid down votes and unplesant comments I reveal that I happen to know that the true translation of the sentence $A \supset B$ of logic to the language of sets (representing events) is $\overline{A \cap \overline B}$.)

Comment: Why $\overline{A \cap \overline B}$ rather than $\overline A \cup B$

Comment: You are right. But I was exercising in using the upper line. The other explanation is that I conceptualise the "set implication" as the complement of the difference. I don't know why.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, it is inconsistent and confusing.

In logic's defense, the $\supset$ notation for logical implication is rare nowadays; it is more often notated $\to$ (Hilbert, 1922) or $\Rightarrow$ (Bourbaki, 1954) -- possibly in recognition of the potential for confusion with the subset/superset relation.

The "$\supset$" symbol for implication was originally a backwards "C" and dates back to Peano (1895). He wrote "$pCq$" for "p is a Consequence of q", and also reversed it to "$q\supset p$ for "q has p as a consequence".

According to some sources, writing "$\subset$" (first used by Schröder, 1890) for "is a subset of" replaced earlier use of "$<$" when authors felt set operations ought to be distinguished from the arithmetic notation that was first used by analogy.

Others claim that "$\subset$" dates back to J. Gergonne (1817) who used "C" for "Contained in".

(Most of the above information is from [Earliest Uses of Various Mathematical Symbols](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html) by Jeff Miller).

Answer (score 2):

I do not know whether this has anything to do with the origin of the use of $\supset$ as $\implies$, but the statements that can be inferred from $A$ when $A \implies B$ include those that can be inferred from $B$.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the notation, not the language itself: it's correct, though confusing, to say in this context $A\subset B$ iff $A\supset B$. I don't know the history of how $\supset$ came to be used for "implies" in logic, and have been bothered by this myself.

Comment: Yes, yes. But I, too, would like to understand the reasons behind. (Only a bad habit, so to speak a misnomer? What might be the historical explanation?)

Comment: Too many f 's up there! A implies B (in logic) does not imply that A is contained in B (as sets).

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are events, or generally if it makes sense to ask whether $A$ is contained in $B$, then I think it does. Am I wrong?

Comment: @zoli you might switch your acceptance to Henning's answer.

Comment: No, thank you. I appreciate that you paid attention to my question. I accepted the agreement part  :) But up voted I the other answer.

Comment: Regarding your remark: "If A and B are events, or generally if it makes sense to ask whether A is contained in B, then I think it does." If A and B are sets rep'ing events then an elementary event may not belong to their union, and yet the implication is TRUE.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but no worries.

Comment: Think of the truth value of the set A as a predicate A(x) which isTRUE if x is in A and is false otherwise.