# Why do we need truth sets?

Tags: logic

> In the last section, we introduced the idea of assigning truth values
> to statements. This idea is unproblematic for statements that do not
> contain variables, since such statements are either true or false. But
> if a statement contains variables, we can no longer describe the
> statement as being simply true or false. Its truth value might depend
> on the values of the variables involved. For example, if P(x) stands
> for the statement “x is a prime number,” then P(x) would be true if x
> = 23, but false if x = 22. To deal with this complication, we will define truth sets for statements containing variables.

This question might seem pretty basic but forgive my ignorance. When I was being taught truth sets it sounded like we use them to deal with predicates that have variables because we can't simply say they are true or false since it depends on the variable, which can change and therefore affect the validity of the statement. How exactly do truth sets help with this? don't I still need to know what the variable is to determine if the statement is true or false?

Comment: Truth sets are found only *after* doing the work of finding out for which value(s) of the variable(s) the given statement with variables is true.

Comment: The "truth set" is the set of "objects" satisfying predicate $P(x)$. With domain the *natural* numbers and predicate "x is Even" the corresponding truth set will be $\{ 2,4,6, \ldots \}$

Comment: Obviously, to determine the truth set we have to identify a *domain* and an interpretation for the non-logical symbols, like the predicate letter $P$ in the example above.

Comment: See these ref [1](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/higher_math_online/section01.05.html#:~:text=There%20is%20a%20natural%20relationship,make%20Q(x)%20true.), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430622/how-to-determine-the-truth-set-of-a-conditional-predicate-if-px-then-qx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of a predicate's “truth set” as abstractly *defining* the predicate, i.e., which variable/tuple values the predicate is true for. For example,

- let the domain of discourse be $\{0,1\},$ and let
  $P(x,y)$ be a predicate with “truth set” $\{ (0,0), (1,1) \}.\quad$ (So, $P(0,1)$ and $P(1,0)$ are both false.)

  Under this interpretation, $$∀y∃xP(x,y)→∃x∀yP(x,y)$$ must be a false
  statement.